# Ограничить длину строки с переносом

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

В html есть элемент:

```
<div class="center-content">
... длинный текст ...
</div>
```

и его стиль в css:

```
.center-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 23%;
}
```

Как можно сделать чтоб на позиции left: 77% он переносился на новую строку?

Comment: нужно обрабатывать селектор overflow-x http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow-x

Comment: @perfect, а он тут причём?

Comment: при том что текст адаптивен и будет переносится на новые строки с градацией равной одному слову. что бы его удержать до определенного процента нужно создать горизонтальную полосу прокрутки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте положение right:

```
.center-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 23%;
    right: 23%;
}
```